# Update thousands rows with different values

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote small program that reorders some of our ids in database to keep maintainability easier and not to need to edit our other programs. It works just fine but I run into issue. Basically I'm currently updating rows like this;

```
UPDATE data SET id = 100 WHERE id = 2000; UPDATE data SET id = 101 WHERE id = 2001; UPDATE data SET id = 102 WHERE id = 2002; ...
```

This one works just fine but not in all scenarios;

```
UPDATE data SET id = 100 WHERE id = 2000;
UPDATE data SET id = 2001 WHERE id = 100; -- Conflight, now the last row got updated again with wrong id
```

The value needs to be updated across multiple tables with specified ids and values only! Is there simple way to run the update query "all at once" so the database does not conflict with already updated ids?

Comment: Yes, the id is indeed primary key

Comment: Someone inserted accidentally id as two billion and our table is about to make integer overflow needing us to reorder it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you may do, is the following:

Add another column "newid", and issue one additional update in the end:

```
UPDATE data   
SET    newid = 100
WHERE  id = 2000;
UPDATE data
SET    newid = 2001
WHERE  id = 100;
```

In the end:

```
UPDATE data
SET    id = newid,
       newid = NULL
WHERE  newid IS NOT NULL;
```

Anyway you need to make sure you don't assign an id twice.

Another way is using a temporary table that exists only in memory:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE idDict AS (
    oldID: int,
    newID: int,
    index oid(oldID)
) ENGINE = MEMORY;

INSERT INTO idDict (oldID,newID) 
VALUES
(2000,100),
(100,2001),
...
;

UPDATE data
JOIN   idDict
ON     data.id = idDict.oldID
SET    data.id = idDict.newID;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE idDict;
```

Note: The index in idDict here is only if you have a really big bunch of updates. The analyzer should use or not use the index properly based upon its assumptions.

Comment: Its not that simple! I need to update the same id to about five different tables and only specified ones!

Comment: This is not stated in the question.

Comment: Oh yeah... I feel dump now. Is it possible to add new column only in the memory? Never really needed.

Comment: That's not possible, but you can use a memory table to do the same, I will add this to my answer

Comment: Thanks, the temporary table was what I needed. Best way to do this simply.